# Issue with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] , trying to redirect to last page?

Tags: php, redirect, server-side

** UPDATE WITH SCRIPT **

Here is a sample of the script i'm trying to run.

```
$lastPage = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo '<script>alert("'.$lastPage.'")</script>'; // this gives me the url I need.  
$_SESSION['lastPage'] = $lastPage;
```

After content is updated, i'm using window.location to redirect to the previous page, like so:

```
echo '<script>window.location="'.$_SESSION['lastPage'].'"</script>'
```

The problem is, the window.location is directing me to the proper url, except it's missing the colon in "http://".

When I alert http_referer as shown in the code above, it gives me the full url, colon and all.

When I try to use it in the window.location, it strips out the colon.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: View the source of when you echo it out and make sure that the value is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [204 status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5) instead of any form of HTML document.

Comment: I'm confused on the 204 status code? Can you expand on that at all?

Comment: FYI, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not guaranteed to exist, nor is it guaranteed to be safe data because it comes from the user. (Not directly related to the question, just a heads up.)

Comment: Hi Matthew,

Thanks for the heads up. I was using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] prior to this, but for some reason, out of nowhere it started returning the path to a style sheet that the wysiwyg uses. If you know of a better way to return the last page via php, that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't redirect with PHP?

```
header("location: ".$_SESSION['lastPage']);
```

Comment: This is what I tried originally. I'm using mod_rewrite to clean up the urls on the site, and for some reason it is causing a problem with storing the page variable in a session. I tried to troubleshoot that for hours, and decided to try another route instead of waste more time.
When I tried it this way, the session was being cleared out after my update script runs, but there is no reason that I was able to find which would cause this to happen. If I remove the rewrite rule from my .htaccess file, the redirect works fine, but the clean urls are essential to the client the website is for.

Comment: another way you can remove http:// from javascript regex and then: window.location.href = "http://" + url_without_http

Comment: or use html metas for redirect: http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I don't really want to use js for the redirect, and I also don't want to run the risk of being blacklisted by google for using meta redirects.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var location = "http://"+ window.location.href.replace(/^http(\:|)\/\//, "");
        window.location.href = location
```